# How to target certain time using jQuery Countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using these jQuery plugin: [jQuery Countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html).

I'm trying to get it to countdown to 17:00 (5:00 PM) everyday but I cannot seem to set the time.

Any help welcomed.

The code I have is:

```
$(function() {
    var now = new Date()
    var since = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDay(), 17, 00);
    $('#noDays').countdown({until: since, format: 'HMS'});
});
```

Timer stucks at 0 with this code.

Comment: Please show your code, and explain what happens when you run it.

Comment: what do you mean by 17:00?  
can you please elaborate , maybe i can help you out , i used this plugin in my own project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (and working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/adZnV/)):

```
$(function() {
    var liftoff = new Date();
    liftoff = new Date(liftoff.getFullYear(), liftoff.getMonth(), liftoff.getDate(), 17, 0, 0);

    $('#noDays').countdown({until: liftoff});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Think your looking for this:

```
var now = new Date()
var since = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDay(), 17, 00);
```

Comment: `$(function() {
 var now = new Date()
var since = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDay(), 17, 00);

        $('#noDays').countdown({until: since, format: 'HMS'});
    });` Does not work. Timer is at 0